# Change background color of main content blocks on different pages

Tags: css, colors, background

I'm trying to get a different background color for each different main content block on the pages on this website: http://www.amachielsenadvies.nl .

So far I have found out that this line in css can control the background color:

```
.sidebarwidth .box.one { background-color: #f8dffc;}
```

but I want a different color on different pages. A page ID i have found is 18 (or post ID), but it is unclear what has to be added in css to accomplish

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page can be uniquely identified through the `page-id-*` class on the body.

So to change the background color on the home page, e.g.

```
.page-id-45 .sidebarwidth .box.one { background-color: #f8dffc;}
```

Comment: @user3354767: Always accept the answer if it worked. You should also include all of the relevant code in your question. Please take the time to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If the page has an ID of 18...`perhaps ID="post-18"` I would assume that this has been applied to the body

```
<body ID="post-18">
```

then the CSS would be

```
#post-18 .sidebarwidth .box.one { background-color: #f8dffc;}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the code before posting an answer? No such ID exists, it's a class.

Comment: Really...then what's this "A page ID i have found is 18"?

Comment: I understand the assumption you made but if you look at the site you'll see he mistakenly referred to it as an ID when it's a class. Just FYI.

Comment: And if that link rots then no future user would be able to make the determination. That's why we ask for **actual** data in the question.

Comment: I agree the code should always be in the question, I just wanted to tell you it was a class so the OP doesn't try your solution and wonder why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the body classes

example

```
body.page-id-18 .sidebarwidth .box.one { background-color: #f8dffc;}
```